# Finding out the difference of months to int in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-views

Im trying to get the difference of months in a project from it's start date to it's end date, and compute it to the monthly updates to show the percentage of a project progress, but my current code doesn't give value to compute. If I remove the .month it says unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

***Models.py***

```
class Projects(models.Model):

id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
project_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
project_manager=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_project_manager' : True})
client_name=models.ForeignKey(Clients,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
project_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='static/website/project-images')
project_start_date=models.DateField(null=True)
project_end_date=models.DateField(null=True)
project_description=models.TextField(null=True)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
objects=models.Manager()

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Project'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.project_name}'



class MonthlyProjectStatus(models.Model):

id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
project_name=models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
project_manager=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
client_name=models.ForeignKey(Clients,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
attachments=models.FileField(upload_to='static/website/files', null=True)
project_update=models.TextField(null=True)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta: 
    verbose_name_plural = 'Monthly Status'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.project_name}'
```

***Views.py***

```
def project_details(request, pk):


projects = Projects.objects.get(id=pk)
employed = Employee.objects.filter(project_site=projects)
invents = Project_Inventory.objects.filter(project_site=projects)
months = MonthlyProjectStatus.objects.filter(project_name=projects).count()

dt = projects.project_start_date.month - projects.project_end_date.month

sums = (months)/(dt) * 100

context = {

    'projects' : projects,
    'employed' : employed,
    'invents' : invents,
    'dt' : dt,
    'months' : months,
    'sums' : sums,

}

template_name ='project-admin/project-details.html'
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differernce between two dates is a `timedelta`. You can convert it to days.

```
d1 = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
d2 = datetime.date(2021,1,1)
dd = d2-d1
days = dd.days  # 366
```

It doesn't support conversion to months, because how long is a month? You can divide by 30 to get an approximation, or work in days.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me and i should really divide it by 30 days to get the approximated month.